# Что такое PATH и как туда поместить файлы?

Tags: windows

Что такое PATH и как туда поместить файлы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PATH - это переменная среды, которая указывает путь поиска исполняемых файлов. В Windows пути прописываются, например, так:

- командой setx из Support Tools: `setx path "%PATH%;C:\New Folder"`,
- изменением ключа реестра: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`,
- в интерфейсе: My Computer -> Properties -> Environment Variable и тп.

Answer (score 5):

> В Windows пути прописываются, например, так:

А в Linux так: (на всякий случай)

```
$ echo ${PATH}
  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin
$ export PATH="${PATH}:/opt/"
$ echo ${PATH}
  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/
```

Команду `export PATH=...` можно поместить в `~/.bashrc`, чтобы не набирать каждый раз.